# Wordpress Error after updating wordpress and plugins

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I started having errors after updating wordpress and my website plugins

```
    Notice: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' in /home4/magist31/public_html/magistraldoces.com/wp-content/themes/sinrato/functions.php on line 74

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home4/magist31/public_html/magistraldoces.com/wp-content/themes/sinrato/functions.php:74) in /home4/magist31/public_html/magistraldoces.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1265

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home4/magist31/public_html/magistraldoces.com/wp-content/themes/sinrato/functions.php:74) in /home4/magist31/public_html/magistraldoces.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1268
```

http://magistraldoces.com/

Answer (score 0):

Only one Notice error is there.

Can you please try to look into /home4/magist31/public_html/magistraldoces.com/wp-content/themes/sinrato/functions.php on line 74.

What related code is there, Any error is there or what exactly.